# ESLint error when importing from redux-saga

Tags: webpack, eslint, redux-saga

Importing redux-saga as follows:

`import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'`

ESLint is raising the following error:

```
 Error while running ESLint: Cannot find module
 '/Users/cjpitt/project/node_modules/redux-saga/config/webpack.config.dev.js'
```

My ESLint config contains import resolvers as follows:

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
        "webpack": {
            "config": "./config/webpack.config.dev.js"
        }
    }
},
```

Repository with example: https://github.com/cjpete/redux-saga-import-issue

Questions:

1. Why could ESLint be trying to use 'node_modules/redux-saga/config/webpack.config.dev.js' to import the module?
2. How do I fix this without changing the import resolvers?

Comment: Not really an answer but it looks like it's a bit of a known problem: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/666 I worked around it by making the `.esltinrc` a JavaScript file and manually resolving the path to the webpack config